# number of leaves is one greater than number of nodes in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have to prove that given a binary tree, the number of leaves is equal to the number of nodes plus one using induction in Haskell. 
Given the following type called Tree:

```
data Tree = Leaf Int | Node Tree Tree
```

I defined two functions called leaves and nodes which return the number of leaves and nodes respectively:

With induction, I know that I need to prove the base case which is when the number of nodes is 0 and for the induction step, I need to use the induction hypothesis. But that's throwing me off here is that there are two functions and I don't really know to proceed.In the base case, am I supposed to show that if the number of nodes is 0, the number of leaves is 1 or?

Answer (score 4):

The tractable way to do this "by induction" is not using [*induction on natural numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) but rather using [*structural induction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction). The proof breaks down like this:

#### Base case

The base case is for `Leaf x`, where `x` is an `Int`. So you have to prove that for any `x`

```
leaves (Leaf x) = 1 + nodes (Leaf x)
```

#### Inductive step

In the inductive step, you assume two inductive hypotheses:

1. `leaves t = 1 + nodes t`
2. `leaves u = 1 + nodes u`

to prove that

```
leaves (Node t u) = 1 + nodes (Node t u)
```

I'll let you fill in the actual proofs.

---

#### Side note:

Structural induction is a generalization of induction on natural numbers. In particular, you can define the natural numbers as

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat
```

You can now do induction with a base case of `p Z`, and an inductive step that assumes `p n` and proves `p (S n)`.

Structural induction can itself be generalized further, to [*well-founded induction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation#Induction_and_recursion), which is the most general mathematical notion of induction of which I am aware. Note that the Wikipedia page is based on a classical notion of well-foundedness; [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/well-founded+relation) gives a constructive version that is more tightly tied to well-founded induction.